# Spring 3: How to handle session based objects between controllers

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-mvc

I generally use Struts2 but I'm exploring the use of Spring for various reasons, most notably the flexibility in the rest-style url capabilities. I thought I would also try to leverage the scoped beans to house some data between controllers. This is a relatively large project and I have a few different controllers to handle different aspects of the site.

What I am running into is that I am declaring a @Component and @Autowiring it in my controllers, but the data is not being persisted between controllers in the session bean.

Bean Example:

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class EventBean implements Serializable {
    private Event event;
    ...
}
```

Controller Example:

```
@Controller
public class EventController {

    @Autowired
    private EventBean event;

    @ModelAttribute("event")
    public EventBean getEvent() {
        return event;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{url}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getEvent(@PathVariable String url, ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("url", url);
        try {
            //  EventEntity in the bean is set by the url from DB
            event.setEvent(url);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(EventController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return "public/index";
    }
}
```

Now what I was aiming for is that if I set the event in this controller, if in a second controller I access the event bean and the entity is not null, there is no need to access the database again.

```
public void setEvent(String url) throws SQLException {
    if (this.event == null) {
        this.event = EventDAO.retrieveByURL(url);
    }
}
```

This doesn't happen though. When I navigate to the second controller the event entity inside the bean is always null.

I've only been toying with Spring for a couple days, so I'm sure I'm missing something, just not sure what I am missing. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

EDIT:

JSP being called:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>
         <h1>Event Name: ${event.name}</h1>
         <h2>Event URL: ${url}</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just to confirm, in your second controller is the event field autowired in also, and is the EventBean correctly wired into the first Controller(field is not null?)

Comment: The second controller is a duplicate of the EventController listed here with the exception of /register is added to the @RequestMapping,  @RequestMapping(value = "/{url}/register", method = RequestMethod.GET). The event.setEvent(url) method is called in the EventController and loads the event entity from the database. I can see the value is populated when stepping through the debugger and I can pull the values using JSTL on the JSP. If I immediately navigate to localhost/myUrl/register, the value of event in the EventBean is not persisted, as though it was never set in the first controller.

Comment: Okay, also are you sure that the first and the second controller are in the scope of a single session, if your jsp has a `<%@ page session="false" %>` there may not be a session itself yet?

Comment: It's a very vanilla setup. The only declarations I have on the JSP page are for taglibs, other than that it is essentially raw. Two actions, 2 JSP's, JSTL taglib, raw HTML, and EL to check the model variables. It's running in Tomcat 7, through Netbeans built as a Maven project. I've added the JSP code to the original post for reference as well.

Comment: My best guess is that your first and second controllers are not in the scope of the same session - could be validated using the session cookie sent for the two requests.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, I'll do some more testing at the office today to verify the session scope of the controllers.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to comment on this. I went back and restructured a few things and it started working. I removed the object from inside the bean class I was trying to set and put a Map<String,Object> in that I could reference instead, seems to have solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options for you to solve this problem. Hope this helps.

1. Use of @SessionAttributes("event"). This would ensure that the Model is stored in session and would be available across container. Your class will look as below. Please note that use of sessionattributes when used across controllers should be done with caution, however I have not run across any problems myself and have used them without issues.

   ```
   @Controller
   @SessionAttributes("event")
   public class EventController {

       @Autowired
       private EventBean event;

       @ModelAttribute("event")
       public EventBean getEvent() {
           return event;
       }

       @RequestMapping(value = "/{url}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public String getEvent(@PathVariable String url, ModelMap model) {
           model.addAttribute("url", url);
           try {
               //  EventEntity in the bean is set by the url from DB
               event.setEvent(url);
           } catch (SQLException ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(EventController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
           }
           return "public/index";
       }
   }
   ```
2. The other options will be to use the form tags provided by spring so that the "event" object is constructed at the request when you are calling the second controller.
   http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring-form-tags-1.html

Comment: Thank you for the input ArunM, I will try it when I get to the office today and let you know how it goes.